# Formatting time using moment JS shows incorrect Date

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I have time coming from server in certain format for example time is `(1473286826319)`. Using MomentJS library

```
moment(1473286826319).format()
// output 2016-09-07T16:20:26-06:00 i.e sep 7 2016
```

However when I use custom formating style as below

```
moment(1473286826319).format('dddd, MMMM d, YYYY, h:mm A');
// output Wednesday, September 3, 2016, 4:20 PM
```

I have the date going back from `Sept 7` to `Sept 3` and rest of the data is accurate. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 9):

You are using a small `d` which is the *Day of Week*. If you want the *Day of Month*  use a `D` or a `DD` for leading zeros.

Checkout the [documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/)